# Is there a way to enforce Nx module boundaries at compile time?

Tags: eslint, nrwl-nx, nrwl, tsconfig.json

My app is using Nx Module Boundaries, the issue is that it is only enforced during linting.

Running at compile time would be preferred.

Only idea so far:
Add lint commands to all of custom package.json npm commands